# StreamBuilder not displaying data as intentioned

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

Been bumbling for a while now with the problem that my items don't appear neatly in the listview after a refresh. For example, what happened when an item with a new date is recognized that there is a new item, but the first item is loaded again, but this time at the bottom. But once the page loads all over again, it does well. See the video: [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJQGartasq0)

This is probably due to the code running right after the StreamBuilder only after the page is restarted. Line

```
else {
      final groupByDates =
      groupBy(snapshot.data, (obj) => obj.tijd.substring(0, 10));
```

This code should therefore also be executed by means of the refresh function. Only how? I have no idea, get stuck on this...

Hopefully someone can help me.

Code:

```
class _BrandweerMeldingenHomeState extends State<BrandweerMeldingenHome> {
  var datums = new List();
  var meldingenBijDatum = new List();
  var capcodesList = new List();
  var voertuigenList = new List();
  var mapDateMelding = new Map();
 
  StreamController _meldingenController;
 
  loadMeldingen() async {
    Meldingen.getMeldingen().then((res) async {
      _meldingenController.add(res);
      return res;
    });
  }
 
  Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
    Meldingen.getMeldingen().then((res) async {
      _meldingenController.add(res);
      return null;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _meldingenController = new StreamController();
    loadMeldingen();
    initializeDateFormatting(); //very important
  }
 
  // Refresh key!
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _meldingenController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            final groupByDates =
                groupBy(snapshot.data, (obj) => obj.tijd.substring(0, 10));
            groupByDates.forEach((date, list) {
              datums.add(date);
              list.forEach((listItem) {
                listItem.capcodes.forEach((items) {
                  capcodesList.add({
                    "id": "${items.id}",
                    "gpkr": "${items.gpkr}",
                    "omschrijving": "${items.omschrijving}",
                  });
                });
                listItem.voertuigen.forEach((items) {
                  voertuigenList.add({
                    "nummer": "${items.nummer}",
                    "type": "${items.type}",
                    "standplaats": "${items.standplaats}",
                  });
                });
                meldingenBijDatum.add({
                  "id": "${listItem.id}",
                  "tijd": "${listItem.tijd}",
                  "melding": "${listItem.melding}",
                  "adres": {
                    "straat": "${listItem.adres.straat}",
                    "plaats": "${listItem.adres.plaats}",
                    "postcode": "${listItem.adres.postcode}",
                    "longitude": "${listItem.adres.longitude}",
                    "latitude": "${listItem.adres.latitude}"
                  },
                  "voertuigen": voertuigenList,
                  "prio": "${listItem.prio}",
                  "capcodes": capcodesList
                });
                capcodesList = [];
                voertuigenList = [];
              });
              mapDateMelding[date] = meldingenBijDatum;
              meldingenBijDatum = [];
            });
            return RefreshIndicator(
              key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
              onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: groupByDates.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return StickyHeader(
                    header: Container(
                        height: 50.0,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                      DateFormat.EEEE('nl')
                                          .format(DateTime.parse(datums[index]))
                                          .toUpperCase(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: ThemeColors.brandweer,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                                  child: Text(
                                      DateFormat.yMMMMd('nl')
                                          .format(DateTime.parse(datums[index]))
                                          .toUpperCase(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: ThemeColors.brandweer,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                              child: new Center(
                                child: new Container(
                                  margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                      start: 1.0, end: 15.0),
                                  height: 2.5,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                    content: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        getItemsWidget(datums[index]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 
  Widget getItemsWidget(index) {
    List<Widget> itemsList = new List();
    List namesString = mapDateMelding[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < namesString.length; i++) {
      itemsList.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MeldingPage(
                      id: namesString[i]['id'],
                      tijd: namesString[i]['tijd'],
                      prio: namesString[i]['prio'],
                      melding: namesString[i]['melding'],
                      adres: namesString[i]['adres'],
                      voertuigen: namesString[i]['voertuigen'],
                      capcodes: namesString[i]['capcodes'])));
        },
        child: SingleMeldingItem(
            tijd: namesString[i]['tijd'],
            prio: namesString[i]['prio'],
            melding: namesString[i]['melding'],
            straat: namesString[i]['adres']['straat'],
            plaats: namesString[i]['adres']['plaats']),
      ));
    }
    Column column = new Column(
      children: itemsList,
    );
    return column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a function that maps the data for me and clears the variables for that. Not the neatest way but fine for now.

```
 fillVariables(res) {
    mapDateMelding.clear();
    voertuigenList.clear();
    capcodesList.clear();
    meldingenBijDatum.clear();
    datums.clear();

    groupByDates.forEach((date, list) {
      ....
      ....
      mapDateMelding[date] = meldingenBijDatum;
      meldingenBijDatum = [];
    });
  }
```